# Center first and last menu item with items above menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Using bootstrap 3, I have:

```
<div class="container"> </div>  {with specific width}
<div class="container-fluid">
 <nav> <nav>

 </div>  {need container-fluid to make mnu background full width}
```

I would like to center first menu item with left edge of picture above and also last menu item to center with right edge of text above.

[Here is a link to the JSFiddle demo.](https://jsfiddle.net/eyh6u3gm)

<sub>Do maximize JS fiddle result window to see menu in full width</sub>

The idea is that space between all menu items is same. I try to get result with some padding of `<a>` tag and `<li>` tag, but for bigger screen I must then write queries. Hence, how do I have an "universal" solution?

Comment: Change the class `container-fluid` on line 21 to just `container`.

Comment: Try that but still no idea, how to order menu items...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `flexbox` to add the property value `space-between` and justify your unordered list items, combined with a media query to prevent affecting your hamburger menu.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-nav {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .navbar-nav > li {
    display: flex;
  }
  .navbar-nav > li > a {
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
}
```

---

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/gm03jquj/)**

---

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */

@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
 .container {
  width: 1100px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.navbar-nav {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.menuCon {
  background: grey;
}
#mainMenu > ul > li > a {
  color: #000;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-nav {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .navbar-nav > li {
    display: flex;
  }
  .navbar-nav > li > a {
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container ">
  <div class="row headRow">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 borderRight width80">
      <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=20&txt=230%C3%9781&w=230&h=81" class="img-responsive logo" id="logo" alt="logo" />
    </div>
    <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-6 col-md-4 mobileMarginText ">
      <div class="headerTextOne">
        <div>top textttttt</div>text text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4  text-left ">
      <p class=" headerPhone">12345678999 710</p>
      <p class=" headerMail">hi@hello.com</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /row menu-->
</div>

<div class="container-fluid menuCont ">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default noBorder height40 menuBox">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed " data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainMenu" aria-expanded="false">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
          </div>

          <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainMenu">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a href="/">First</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="/">Home1</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="/">Home2</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="/">Home3</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="/">Home4</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="/">Last</a>
              </li>

            </ul>

          </div>
          <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
      </nav>


    </div>




  </div>
</div>
```